# List style selection orange glitches Gingerbread

Tags: java, android

I have very strange glitches when using just a simple list UI on Gingerbread:
[image]

Does anyone know where this might come from?

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Rows:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        layout_alignParentTop="true"
        gravity="center_vertical"
        padding="5dp"
        textColor="#FFFFFF"
        typeface="monospace" />
```

Comment: We need a lot more information than this... What's the layout for your list items?

Comment: sorry, added row xml. but I think I'm not doing anything special there.